# How to reproduce sample dataset from a given regression model in R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate sample data from the following regression model with given parameters.

y = 2.6306 * exp(0.0536 * x)

R^2 = 0.7811, n = 100, 3 < x < 15

I used the following code to generate the data:

```
gen_sample <- function(a, b, r_sq, n, xmin, xmax){
  x <- seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = n)
  error <- rnorm(n, sd = sqrt((1 - r_sq) * var(a * exp(b * x))))
  y <- a * exp(b * x) + error
  
  # Fit the curve
  model <- nls(y ~ a * exp(b * x), start = list(a = a, b = b))
  
  return(list("x" = x, "y" = y, "model" = model))
}

sample <- gen_sample(a = 2.98, 
                          b = 0.106, 
                          r_sq = 0.61, 
                          n = 25, 
                          xmin = 8, 
                          xmax = 18)
summary(sample$model)$r.squared
```

However, when I tried to check the R-squared value using summary(sample$model)$r.squared, it returned "NULL". I learned that this is because a nonlinear model fitted with nls() does not produce an R-squared value. So, I tried to calculate the R-squared value manually using the following code:

```
# Calculate TSS and RSS
y_mean <- mean(sample$y)
TSS <- sum((sample$y - y_mean)^2)
RSS <- sum(resid(sample$model)^2)

# Calculate R-squared
R2 <- 1 - RSS/TSS
R2

> R2
[1] 0.6762711
```

But, the calculated R2 value is different from the initial R-squared value I specified (0.7811). Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?"

Comment: For testing, you should massively increase n, say to `n = 1e4`, to limit the impact of randomness.

Comment: @Roland; Thank you for your comment. the result still shows "NULL" even if I increased it to 1e6. It takes too long for the operation to finish if I increase more than this

Comment: The result will always be `NULL` because the object doesn't contain an R-squared value. I'm referring to your calculated R-squared.

Comment: In the call to `gen_sample` you pass `r_sq = 0.61`, not 0.78.

Comment: My mistake. ```r_sq = 0.61``` is the correct value